# Finding a counterexample of the following statement

Tags: functions

This statements is false so I have to find a counterexample.

Statement: If $f:A \to B$ is injective iff $g\circ f = h\circ f$ for all function $g,h:B \to A$.

**Attempt:**
Let $A=\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$ and $B = \Bbb Z$. I define $f:A \to B$ as: $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\left(1-(-1)^x(2x+1)\right)$ and define $g,h:B \to A$ as:
\begin{equation*}
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2x, & x \ge 0 \\
-(2x+1), & x < 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and $h(x) = |x|$.

Is it true?

Comment: You can make your argument way simpler. Consider $A=B=\mathbb{R}$, $f=g=\text{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$, and $h(x)=x^3$

Comment: @MatthewPilling But, is my example above true?

Comment: It's true, but if you want to accurately show that this is in fact a counterexample to $\implies$ you would have to prove that $f$ is injective and that $g\circ f \neq h\circ f$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, but you still have to prove that it is correct by showing that $f$ is injective and that $g\circ f\ne h\circ f$. Your definition of $f$ is far more complicated than is necessary or desirable: the function is simply

$$f(n)=(-1)^{n+1}\left\lceil\frac{n}2\right\rceil=\begin{cases}
-\frac{n}2,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\frac{n+1}2,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\,.
\end{cases}$$

The first of these definitions is about as compact as you can get, and the second is probably the easiest to work with. Then you can check that

$$(g\circ f)(n)=\begin{cases}
n+1,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
n-1,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$(h\circ f)(n)=\begin{cases}
\frac{n}2,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\frac{n+1}2,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

and easily demonstrate that these are different functions.

I’ll point out, however, that there are much simpler counterexamples. The simplest is this one:

> Let $A=B=\{0,1\}$, $f(a)=a$ for $a\in A$, $g(b)=b$ for $b\in B$, and $h(b)=1-b$ for $b\in B$.